# How to retrieve the css property of an element whose css value is dynamically changing?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

In our browser developer tools there is no id, so we are using css value. But css value `(css=#estimateTable[_ngcontent-c20].highlighted[_ngcontent-c20])` is changing dynamically. so we are getting an error message stating

Element with locator `css=#estimateTable[_ngcontent-c20].highlighted[_ngcontent-c20]` not found.

```
<tr _ngcontent-c5="" class="item-name highlighted" tabindex="0">
<td _ngcontentc5="">
<div _ngcontent-c5="" class="svg-size cursor" style="text-align:center; 
  padding-top:12px;">
<mat-icon _ngcontent-c5="" class="mat-icon" role="img" svgicon="common:estimatetmp" aria-hidden="true">
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fit="" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false">
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs>
</defs>
  <g id="__26Nzx83__estimate-tmp-icon" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
  <g id="__26Nzx83__Group-2">
  <rect id="__26Nzx83__Rectangle-4-Copy-2" fill="#FFFFFF" x="0" y="0" width="32" height="32"></rect>
  <g id="__26Nzx83__Group" transform="translate(4.000000, 4.000000)">
  <rect id="__26Nzx83__Rectangle-3" fill="#9013FE" opacity="0.25" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" rx="2">
  </rect>
  <text id="__26Nzx83__E" font-family="OpenSans-ExtraBold, Open Sans" font-size="18" font-weight="600" fill="#FFFFFF">
  <tspan x="7" y="19">E</tspan>
  </text>
  </g>
  </g>
  </g>
</svg>
</mat-icon>
</div>
</td>
<td _ngcontent-c5="" class="fontStyle" data-placement="top" title="Untitled Estimate 74"> Untitled Estimate 74 </td>
<td _ngcontent-c5="" class="fontStyle">venkatesh kumar</td>
<td _ngcontent-c5="" class="fontStyle">Oct 31 2018 11:28 AM</td>
<td _ngcontent-c5="">
<div _ngcontent-c5="" class="dropdown">
<div _ngcontent-c5="" class="options more-icon item-name" data-placement="top" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color: black; font-size: 24px;">
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

How to handle this? Shall we tried using `class name"(class=item.highlighted)` instead of css and id but couldn't locate.

Comment: Have you tried [AngularJSLibrary](https://github.com/Selenium2Library/robotframework-angularjs)? Despite the name including JS, supports both Angular 2.0+ (known as simply Angular) and Angular 1.0 (also known as Angular JS).

Comment: What is your exact usecase? Question heading says _...retrieve the css property..._ but in description _...locator 'css='foo'..._

Comment: Post the relevant HTML. Make sure you clearly identify what is changing with each refresh.

Comment: @DebanjanB. We need to check the background-color: for that we are retrieving the styles using Css: #estimateTable[_ngcontent-c23] .highlighted[_ngcontent-c23]. This Css value is dynamically changing. How to get the correct css for checking background color.